# Regex matching behavior with multi-character unicode symbol

Tags: regex, unicode, pcre

I am having trouble understanding some behavior I observed with multi-character unicode symbols.

Take, as an example, the string , and the regex `(|)(?![])`, I get three matches: Both flags, and the last hand. *Expected:* 5 matches, each symbol once.

Since both  and  are 2 character symbols, I tried writing a non-unicode example. With the string `abcdabcdab` and the regex `(ab|cd)(?![b])`, I get the expected 5 matches, each pair of `ab` and `cd` once.

Thinking that there might be some interaction between  and , I used a different unicode character, giving me the regex `(|)(?![])`. Here I get the same result that I got in the first example.

Since both  and  are usually not used individually, I tried using "normal" unicode or ASCII characters instead of . I my example, I used  and `a`, which gave me the expected result of 5 matches, each symbol once.

Is someone able to explain this behavior, or is this a bug?

This behavior only happened in PCRE and the JavaScript regex engine, I used this site to test it. https://regex101.com/

Comment: You should not have put a multibyte character inside a character class, you just need to remove the brackets, `(|)(?!)`. Inside the character class, it got "decomposed" into a sequence of two bytes, `\uD83C\uDFFE` matching either of them, not as a sequence, and the hand emoji is a sequence of `\uD83E\uDD1A\uD83C\uDFFE` (it ends with these two bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put a multibyte character inside a character class like in `(?![])`. Inside the character class, it got "decomposed" into a sequence of two bytes,  `\uD83C` and `\uDFFE` , matching either of them, not as a sequence. As the hand emoji is a sequence of `\uD83E\uDD1A\uD83C\uDFFE` (it ends with these two bytes), the lookahead got triggered and affected the matches.

To solve the problem, you just need to remove the brackets and use `(|)(?!)` so that the  char could be treated as a *byte sequence*, not one or another char.